# python can not get the output right for dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

the file contains following string:

```
I have no pride     
I have no shame   
You gotta make it rain    
Make it rain rain rain
```

output should look like this:

```
 {'rain': [2, 3], 'gotta': [2], 'make': [2], 'it': [2, 3], 'shame': [1], 'I': [0, 1], 'You': [2], 'have': [0, 1], 'no': [0, 1], 'Make': [3], 'pride': [0]}
```

but I am getting this:

```
{'I': 1, 'have': 1, 'gotta': 2, 'Make': 3, 'it': 3, 'rain': 3, 'You':
 2, 'no': 1, 'make': 2, 'shame': 1, 'pride': 0}
```

My code:

```
def lineIndex(fName):
    fileName=open(fName)
    contents=fileName.readlines()
    fileName.close()
    d={}
    lst=[]
    count=-1
    for line in  contents:
        if line not in lst:
            print(line)
            lst.append(line)
            count+=1

        t=line.split()
        y2=[]    
        for eachWord in t:
            #print(eachWord)
            if eachWord not in d:
                y2.append(eachWord)
                d[eachWord]=count
            if eachWord in d:
                d[eachWord]=count

    return d
```

Comment: Hopefully I formatted right

Comment: It is not quite clear how you are getting these output. Can you explain the logic behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
from collections import defaultdict
with open('your_file.txt','r') as f:
    result = defaultdict(set)
    counter =0
    for line in f:
        for item in line.split():
            result[item].add(counter)
        counter +=1
    print {i[0]:list(i[1]) for i in result.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'no': [0, 1], 'I': [0, 1], 'gotta': [2], 'it': [2, 3], 'rain': [2, 3], 
'shame': [1], 'have': [0, 1], 'You': [2], 'pride': [0], 'Make': [3], 'make': [2]}
```

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I have included the output also. I am not clear about your objection here.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you'd initialized it to a set.

Comment: Of course, the order on a set is arbitrary, so you might not get a sorted list for each value.

Comment: No problem, it's okay. To be frank, now your approach seems to be a better one. +1

Comment: Yeah true, I could fix it with `sorted`, but this is too much for this task, let's keep intact, and let's see what OP thinks about it.  Your `set(line.split())` is clearly a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
y2=[]
for eachWord in t:
    #print(eachWord)
    if eachWord not in d:
        y2.append(eachWord)
        d[eachWord]=count
    if eachWord in d:
        d[eachWord]=count
```

You keep resetting each key's value to the latest line number. Instead, try a `collections.defaultdict` to make each value start with a list by default, and enumerate the lines to get the count:

```
import collections

def lineIndex(fName):
    d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    with open(fName) as f:
        for idx,line in enumerate(f):
            for word in set(line.split()):
                d[word].append(idx)
    return d
```

Comment: can it be done with simple for loops? We have not learned for idx,line in enumerate(f).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution without any imported module:

```
d = {}
with open("rain.txt") as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
        for word in line.split():
            if word in d:
                if i not in d[word]:
                    d[word].append(i)
            else:
                d[word] = [i]
print(d)
```

The result looks like this:

```
{'no': [0, 1], 'gotta': [2], 'make': [2], 'rain': [2, 3], 'I': [0, 1], 
'You': [2], 'Make': [3], 'have': [0, 1], 'pride': [0], 'it': [2, 3], 
'shame': [1]}
```

Alternative without enumerate:

```
d = {}
with open("rain.txt") as f:
    frl = f.readlines()
    for i in range(len(frl)):
        line=frl[i]
        for word in line.split():
            if word in d:
                if i not in d[word]:
                    d[word].append(i)
            else:
                d[word] = [i]
print(d)
```

Comment: can it be done with simple for loops? We have not learned for idx,line in enumerate(f).

Comment: for i in rangeenumerate(f.readlines()):
        for word in line.split():
            if word in d:
                if i not in d[word]:
                    d[word].append(i)
            else:
                d[word] = [i]
print(d)

Comment: Last comment has been sent accidentally.

 frl = f.readlines()
 for i in len(range(frl)):
        line = frl[i]
        for word in line.split():
            if word in d:
                if i not in d[word]:
                    d[word].append(i)
            else:
                d[word] = [i]